# How to have VSCode move the opening bracket / brace to a new line on enter like Visual Studio does

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio, when you type an opening bracket and press enter, it automatically puts it in a new line.

```cs
// before pressing enter
public class Item { /* cursor here */ }

// after pressing enter
public class Item
{
    // cursor here
}
```

How can I reproduce this behaviour with Visual Studio Code?

I tried adding a `omnisharp.json` and a `.editorconfig`, but neither have worked.